# clever way to write numbers as sortable text?

Tags: java, text, ascii

The naive approach is `printf("%10d",num)` but if number is greater than 10 digits then this process will fail.

Take `printf("%2d",num)` for example and these numbers 1, 12, 100
They will write out as: 01,12 and 100 but will sort alphanumerically as 01, 100, 12 which is wrong.

To get the answer right, it must be sortable as plain ASCII text.

Most of the numbers written out will be small and occasionally it will be large numbers written out. For space concerns padding with zeros isn't that great way of doing it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use a custom comparator?

Comment: why not determine the highest number of digits and then simply create the printf string like "%" + HighestNumberOfDigits + "d"?

Comment: No you cannot change the compare. In this problem I can only change how I write the date out. Prefix in the numbers with lots of zeros will cause a lot of bloat in the file. Hence I'm wondering if there is a clever way to write out the numbers. The only criteria is that they must be monotonically increasing as sorted by Alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If large numbers appear only occasionally, than you could prefix your small numbers with '+', and for your large numbers, use as many leading zeros such that the group of large numbers is sorted correctly. For example, the following list is sorted 'correctly':

```
+01
+12
000100
```

Of course, you have to proof that the "trick" of preceding a number with '+' does not break any code reading in these lists again.

Comment: I like your suggestion. Thinking more about it in some sense if wrote the exponent first and then the mantissa, I think it might work for very large numbers as well as very small numbers.

Comment: have you considered maintaining the number as such instead of text, and converting them to string only when you need to? it makes it very easy to sort, and if you have a large number of items, int[] is going to take considerably less memory than String[].

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Stephan Lechner's insight,

```
String sortable(long n) {
    int radix = 36;
    int exponent= (int) floor(log10(n));
    String x = Long.toString(exponent, radix)+Long.toString(n, radix);
    return x;
}

@Test
public void test() {        
    out.println(sortable(1));
    out.println(sortable(20));      
    out.println(sortable(200));
    out.println(sortable(100000));
    out.println(sortable(10000000));
    out.println(sortable(12466521));
    out.println(sortable(20000000));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
01
1k
25k
5255s
75yc1s
77f789
7bwo3k
```

That's far shorter than outputting `00000000000000000001` for `1` and the rest.
(A 64 long can take up to 20 chars.)